# Speed up double summation

Tags: performance-tuning, summation

Is there any way how to speed up this double summation?

```
(*Define Function*)
a = -0.07;
b = -0.45;
c = 2.;
d = 3.;
tau = 2.;
dt=10.^-2;
e = c*tau;
ft[t1_] = a*Exp[-t1/d] - b*Exp[-t1/e];
g[t1_, t2_, t3_] = ft[t1]*ft[t2]*ft[t3];

factor[x_, y_] := factor[x, y] = g[0., x*dt, y*dt]
sumfactor[h_, g_] := Sum[factor[x, y], {x, 0, h}, {y, 0, g}]

Module[{k = 3000}, sumfactor[k, k]]
```

For arguments like 3000 in the function `sumfactor` this is pretty slow unfortunately.

Comment: Does `tau2` have a value? What about `dt`?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Edited my post. The values are of no importance. It is more a programming style question.

Comment: You can reduce it by a factor of about two by noting that `factor[x,y] == factor[y,x]`, so you need only iterate for `y > x`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use vectorization.

```
factor[x_, y_] = g[0., x*dt, y*dt]
```

Assuming `h=g=3000`:

```
xx = ConstantArray[N@Range[0, 3000], 3001];
yy = Transpose[xx];

Total[factor[xx, yy], 2] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.375605, 253819.} *)
```

The key is to pass in a vector (or matrix) containing all possible x, y values, and operate on the entire array at once. This works well if you only use scalar operations, like here.  If you use any vector operations, like `Dot`, you must be careful to ensure that the operation does what you expect, even on a matrix.

---

Your code for comparison:

```
factor[x_, y_] := factor[x, y] = g[0., x*dt, y*dt]
sumfactor[h_, g_] := Sum[factor[x, y], {x, 0, h}, {y, 0, g}]

Module[{k = 3000}, sumfactor[k, k]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {88.9004, 253819.} *)
```

Comment: There is some additional information. Exp is Listable, otherwise, it won't work. If Exp is not a Listable Function and Exp can't accept a list as parameter, then you can use SetAttributes[f,{Listable}] to make it Listable.

Comment: Good to know, thank you!

Comment: @DisplayName That's a bit misleading. The `Listable` attribute on its own brings no improvements in performance. Many basic functions like `Exp`, `Sin`, etc. can operate on arrays, and use an efficient parallelized implementation under the hood.  If you define your own function, then make it `Listable` explicitly, you will lose this performance. http://i.stack.imgur.com/V1GRC.png That's because you're back to evaluating the function for each element of the array separately (instead of using true vectorization).

Answer (score 5):

There is a much faster way. Since the sumand is quite simple, you can get an analytic expression of your sum.

There are two ways, either with Rationalize or without.

```
 su[h_, g_] =Sum[Rationalize[factor[x, y], 0], {x, 0, h}, {y, 0, g}]

 su2[h_, g_] = Sum[factor[x, y], {x, 0, h}, {y, 0, g}]
```

Results not schown here, because to long.

Then you don't need to sum up, but just evaluate the calculated functions su or su2

```
 N[su[2000, 2000], 30] // Timing

 (*     {2.47025*10^-15, 9486.97325178896101045672676230}    *)

 N[su2[2000, 2000], 30] // Timing

 (*    {8.32667*10^-17, 9486.97}     *)
```

Exactly the same as your result

```
 N[sumfactor[2000, 2000], 30] // Timing

 (*    {17.688, 9486.97}    *)
```

Answer (score 2):

In version 12.1, you can speed up the accepted answer from Szabolcs with `FunctionCompile`:

```
cf = FunctionCompile[
  Function[{Typed[k, "MachineInteger"]},
   Module[{a, b, c, d, tau, dt, e, ft, g, factor, xx, yy},
    a = -0.07;
    b = -0.45;
    c = 2.0;
    d = 3.0;
    tau = 2.0;
    dt = 0.01;
    e = c*tau;
    xx = ConstantArray[N@Range[0, k], k + 1]; yy = Transpose[xx];
    Typed[
      KernelFunction[
       Total], {TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 2], 
        "MachineInteger"} -> 
       "Real64"][(a*Exp[0.0] - b*Exp[0.0])*(a*Exp[-xx*dt/d] - 
        b*Exp[-xx*dt/e])*(a*Exp[-yy*dt/d] - b*Exp[-yy*dt/e]), 2]
    ]]]

cf[3000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

I get about a 3x speed up this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing the whole calculation with symbols and substituting only at the end:

```
ft[t1_] = a*Exp[-t1/d] - b*Exp[-t1/e];
g[t1_, t2_, t3_] = ft[t1]*ft[t2]*ft[t3];
factor[x_, y_] = factor[x, y] = g[0, x*dt, y*dt];
sumfactor[h_, g_] = Sum[factor[x, y], {x, 0, h}, {y, 0, g}] // FullSimplify
(*    (1/((-1 + E^(dt/d))^2 (-1 + E^(dt/e))^2))(a - b) E^(-((dt (d + e) (g + h))/(d e))) (a E^((dt g)/e) (-1 + E^(dt/e)) (-1 + E^((dt (1 + g))/d)) - b E^((dt g)/d) (-1 + E^(dt/d)) (-1 + E^((dt (1 + g))/e))) (a E^((dt h)/e) (-1 + E^(dt/e)) (-1 + E^((dt (1 + h))/d)) - b E^((dt h)/d) (-1 + E^(dt/d)) (-1 + E^((dt (1 + h))/e)))    *)

sumfactor[3000, 3000] //. {a -> -0.07, b -> -0.45, c -> 2, d -> 3, tau -> 2, dt -> 10^-2, e -> c*tau}
(*    9617.85    *)
```

In this way the calculation is accurate and immediate.